# json deserialize using jackson api

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-mvc

**pojo class**

```
class Authentication {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 3808270497038004505L;

    public Authentication(){
}

private String userName;

private String passWord;

public String getuserName() {
    return userName;
}

public void setuserName(String userName) {
    userName = userName;
}

public String getpassWord() {
    return passWord;
}

public void setpassWord(String passWord) {
    passWord = passWord;
}
}
```

**controller**

```
Authentication authentication= (Authentication) new JSONDeserializer<T>().deserialize(data,Authentication.class);
 return new ModelAndView().addObject(authentication);
```

**passing data**

```
  {"userName":"kadires","passWord":"ramgopal"}
```

**result**

```
System.out.println(authentication.getpassWord()+authentication.getuserName());

{"authentication":{"userName":null,"passWord":null}}
```

please help me

Comment: What would you like to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Check if your setters are correctly written. First letter after get must be uppercase.

Also you could create your implementation of NullSerializer. For example:

```
public class NullSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeString("");
    }
}
```

Then just set your NullSerializer to the ObjectMapper:

```
ObjectMapper objMapper = new ObjectMapper();
StdSerializerProvider sp = new StdSerializerProvider();
sp.setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());
objMapper.setSerializerProvider(sp);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem are probably the setters, they start with lower case setuser... setpassword, use upper case for first letter, it is the convention.